# Visual Studio Code: How to change color of '->' and '.' operators in C?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code, textmate, vscode-extensions

I'm trying out VS Code, but I would like to use my Sublime color settings.  I've used the 'yo code' tool as suggested by the installation instructions to import the settings as TextMate.  This worked mostly, however I cannot figure out how to change the syntax of the indirection operators '->' and '.' in the C language.

I assume it should be in the field here:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>keyword.operator</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>keyword.operator</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#aaaaaa</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Here is an example screenshot of the differences:

Sublime:

[image: sublime]

VS Code:

[image: VS Code]